# django-elasticsearch-dsl with AWS elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use AWS ElasticBeanStalk to deploy a Django app using `django-elasticsearch-dsl` and I need to run `./manage.py search_index --rebuild` the first time I load it.  So within my container commands I've got:

```
03_elasticsearch:
  command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && ./src/manage.py search_index --rebuild"
```

The problem is it is waiting for a n/Y to the question `Are you sure you want to delete the 'hjsm-local' indexes? [n/Y]:`

How do I rebuild my indecies?

**UPDATE**

When I use

```
03_elasticsearch:   
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && ./src/manage.py search_index --rebuild -f"
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 134, in handle
  self._rebuild(models, options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 114, in _rebuild
  self._create(models, options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 84, in _create
  index.create()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 102, in create
  self.connection.indices.create(index=self._name, body=self.to_dict(), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
  return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 110, in create
  params=params, body=body)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
  status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 110, in perform_request
  self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 114, in _raise_error
  raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
  elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: <exception str() failed>
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [source code](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl/blob/1072bcfc18f293fb8ec5258772794357d3fcc3be/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py#L46-L51), include the `-f` parameter in your command to force the acceptance of the prompt.

Comment: I've tried that but I get the attached error when I do that

Comment: @HenryM are you able to delete and then rebuild the indices? If so, that would indicate there's an error in the way the app rebuilds indices.

Comment: I don't know elasticsearch and I'm just trying to set it up.  When I run locally using a local elasticsearch it works so I think the issue is with how I'm connecting to AWS elasticsearch or how I've set up the aws elasticsearch

Comment: @HenryM I mean what happens if you add another command before the one that's failing where you run `manage.py search_index --delete -f` before you do the rebuild one.

Comment: I don't run --delete because it does that as part of rebuild.  other commands work fine (for example `manage.py migrate`).  It is crashing when trying to create the index

Comment: Ah I missed that reading the source. I don't know what the problem is then. Perhaps file an issue against django-elasticsearch-dsl.